# Custom Font Visible in Storyboard but not Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

For some reason, the font that I have added to the Xcode Project is showing in the `Storyboard` but not in the `Simulator`.

Here is the `Storyboard`.[image: Storyboard Image]

Here is the `Simulator`. [image: Simulator Image]

As you can see, the two fonts are not the same. I have seen similar posts on Stack Overflow, but all of these posts suggest solutions that I already have tried or made sure are enabled. I have made sure that the project is the target, it is in copy bundled resources, and it has been added to the `info.plist`. Here are some more screenshots:
[image: <code>P List</code> Image]
[image: Target Membership Image]
[image: <code>Copy Bundled Resources</code> Image]

As this is a brand new project and I have only worked in storyboard mode, no code could be interfering with the text.

Comment: Do you add your target each font itself ?

Comment: I only have the option to target the folder containing all of the fonts to the project.

Comment: Adds the fonts into the app, rather than the containing folder, and make sure all of them are are members of your target

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I just had to add the fonts independently not in a folder.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ashley Mills, I was able to determine that the issue was I added the fonts in a folder and not independently. Adding the fonts separately fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

## Troubleshooting

You can do this adding custom font to your project following:

- Add all font files to your project navigator.
- Add font names(with the file extension) to `info.plist`. (or do it in code, comment to ask me how)
- Check if the font name matches the font name, not it's file name!
- Check if each font is added to target.
- Use following code to print out all fonts in the app:

anywhere after app lunched

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName) {
        print(fontName)
    }
}
```